# Flutter - How to clear text field on focus

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I remove all text from a `TextFormField` on focus? This was very easy in JavaScript: `onfocus="this.value=''";`. I don't want to use a button like this:

```
FlatButton(onPressed: () => _textFieldcontroller.clear(), ...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`FocusNode`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) in combination with a `StatefulWidget`.

We keep an object of `FocusNode` in our class:

```
FocusNode _focusNode;
```

In the constructor of our `TextFormField`, we will have to pass `_focusNode` as a parameter:

```
TextFormField(focusNode: _focusNode, ...
```

Now we can add a listener to our `FocusNode` that will always get called when the focus of our `TextFormField` updates. In it, we can check whether our `FocusNode` has focus or not and take action according to that.

```
_focusNode.addListener(() {
  if (_focusNode.hasFocus) _textFieldController.clear();
});
```

In a widget:

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleWidgetState createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  FocusNode _focusNode;
  TextEditingController _textFieldController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) _textFieldController.clear();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => TextFormField(focusNode: _focusNode, controller: _textFieldController, ...);
}
```